# How to do equality test for derived classes

Tags: c++

How to create an efficient `equals` method for derived classes?

```
struct Base {
    virtual bool equals(const Base &other) const = 0;
};
```

The usual answer is to use `dynamic_cast` or `typeid` to check type identity in derived classes, and if type matches then do a compare:

```
struct Derived: Base {
    virtual bool equals(const Base &other) const override {
        if (typeid(*this)!=typeid(other)) return false;

        return *this==static_cast<Derived &>(other);
    }
};
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this type check? What can we do if we have RTTI disabled?

Comment: If you're willing to go against the Liskov substitution principle (doing that introduces other trade-offs that may or may not be acceptable to you) use double dispatch.

Comment: @Peter: do you mean a solution where all the derived types need to be listed in some form?

Comment: Well, yeah.   If you want behaviour that depends on type without testing the type (or type ID) it is necessary to do something specific for each type that matters.

Answer (score 1):

I think the core issue is that you shouldn’t need to compare types. That need always shows a poor design, incorrect usage of inheritance, or other bad patterns.

Look why you would need the equality information - what are you going to do with it *next* that you couldn’t do by calling an onherited and overwritten method of the classes?

Comment: In general, I agree with you. But there can be cases, where this functionality is useful. For example, removing an element from a container by value. For types without `operator==`, this can only be implemented with some kind of token (add returns a token which can be used at remove).

Comment: This problem comes up when you want to implement multicast functions, [Herb Sutter talks about this](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/generalizing-observer/184403873). Unfortunately, as it turned out, current C++ lamba's cannot be compared for equality either, so this cannot be done with current C++ without using tokens.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen this "trick", so I'll add it here:

```
struct Base {
    virtual bool equals(const Base &other) const = 0;

    virtual const void *typeMarker() const = 0;
};

struct Derived: public Base {
    static char s_typeMarker;

    virtual bool equals(const Base &other) const override {
        if (&s_typeMarker!=other.typeMarker()) return false;

        return *this==static_cast<Derived &>(other);
    }

    virtual const void *typeMarker() const override {
        return &s_typeMarker;
    }
};
```

Basically, it has a `typeMarker()` virtual function, which returns a unique value for each type. So, type equality check is done with a virtual function call (and a compare), which can be cheaper than `typeid` or `dynamic_cast`, and this method works with RTTI disabled.

The only drawback I know is this might not work correctly across .dlls.

(Based on this answer, maybe someone can come up with a better solution.)